# Wake up the modern standby machine when data receive over http

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, standby

I saw this example which can receive the data over the socket even when machine is in sleep (Connected modern standby).
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket

Is it possible to receive the data over the HTTP instead of TCP socket?

I am using libcurl to maintain http downchannel to the server. When server has some data for the app, it directly push to the app.

```
LibCurlEasy.curl_easy_setopt(Handle, CurlEasyOption.TcpKeepAlive, 1L);

            onReceiveDataCallback = OnReceiveDataCallback;
            onReceiveHeaderCallback = OnReceiveHeaderCallback;
            onReadDataCallback = OnReadDataCallback;

            LibCurlEasy.curl_easy_setopt(Handle, CurlEasyOption.WriteFunction, onReceiveDataCallback);
```

When machine goes to sleep, how can i transfer the ownership of http, so that i can receive the data from background thread as the app will be suspended on sleep mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTP is generally just TCP port 80 so I would think it possible.  Also, I see you are using UWP, Windows might treat those apps differently in sleep mode and not allow them to run?

Comment: That example uses StreamSocket.TransferOwnership to transfer an applications socket to a socket brokering service on the machine.  It's a UWP feature that allows a running process to keep the socket open even if the application goes into the background, it does not keep the socket open while a machine sleeps.